# Order items In Flex layout with three columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following HTML && CSS:

```
.circular-progress {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;

  &.layer-view {
    width: 96px;
    height: 96px;
  }
}

.inner-circle {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  background-color: rgb(255,255,255);

  &.layer-view {
    position: relative;
    padding: 40px;
  }
}

.matching-score-item {
  margin-top: -6px;
  max-width: 350px;
}

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex">
  <div>
    <div class="circular-progress layer-view mt-2 me-2" style="background: conic-gradient(rgb(250, 92, 124) 118.8deg, rgb(238, 242, 247) 0deg);">
      <div class="inner-circle layer-view">
        <p class="layer-view-matching-score d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
          2/6
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="p-2 flex-grow-1">
    <p>
      Column 1 Item 1 
    </p>

    <p>
      Columns 1 Item 2
    </p>

    <p>
      Columns 1 Item 3
    </p>

    <p>
      Columns 1 Item 4
    </p>
  </div>  
  
  <div class="p-2 flex-grow-1">
    <p>
      Column 2 Item 1 
    </p>

    <p>
      Columns 2 Item 2
    </p>

    <p>
      Columns 2 Item 3
    </p>

    <p>
      Columns 2 Item 4
    </p>
  </div>    
</div>
```

In this layout **Columns 1 Item 3** and **Columns 1 Item 4** are optional and sometimes they will not be present in the layout. In that case in first column we have 2 items and in second column we have 4 items which doesn't look good:

https://jsfiddle.net/u65sk2re/2/

Is there any way of fixing this?

Comment: Why not use align-self: center on the first column. If there are 4 items then it would render as it is. And if it is 2, then it would render in a center.

Comment: Define *which doesn't look good*. What should it look like?